# Add column to query result based on operations

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We are trying to achieve an incremental sync.

We have a table `OBJECTS` like this:

```
ID | ACTIVE | CREATED | MODIFIED | CONTENT
1    1        1234      1235       text
```

The client sends the server his last sync date (a long integer).

```
[S = LastSync; C = created; M = Modified]
```

The query selects only rows with `M>S`.

When need to a new column `ACTION` that can be `0` (insert), `1` (update) or `2` (delete) [used to tell clients what to do].

`ACTION` will follow these rules:

```
if(C==M && S<M) return 0; //Object created, not modified, last sync before creation

if(C<M && C<S<M && ACTIVE == 1) return 1; //Object modified, still active, sync between creation and modification

if(C<M && C<S<M && ACTIVE == 0) return 2; //Object modified, not active, sync between creation and modification

if(C<M && S<C) return 0; //Object modified, last sync before creation
```

Is there a way to do all this with a query in `MySQL`?

Comment: Why are you using PHP to sync two databases? Just use the replication function of mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html

Comment: Valid point. Android has only SQLite. And to tell you, there is no such a combined query. You need to make the query for each action. Only 0 and 1 can be combined (called REPLACE). Take the mysql manual as reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sql query logic for your '4-if conditions' (only)... try if it work for you:

`select ((created<modified) + (created<LastSync) + (LastSync<modified) - 
((active or LastSync<created) and (created<Modified)) - 1) as action;`